# Altering MySQL table to add foreign key constraint leads to errors

Tags: mysql

## Question:

Why am I getting errors when trying to alter a table with a foreign key constraint?

## Details:

I have 1 table, `HSTORY` which I use as a base table for all other specific history tables (ie. `USER_HISTORY`, `BROWSER_HISTORY`, `PICTURE_HISTORY`...).  I have also included the `PICTURE` and `USER` tables as they get called as well.

**HISTORY table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS HISTORY
(
   ID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   VIEWERID  INT NOT NULL ,
   VIEWDATE  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),

   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (VIEWERID) REFERENCES USER(ID)
)
engine=innodb;
```

**USER table:** (in case anyone is curious)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER
(
   ID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
engine=innodb;
```

**PICTURE table:** (in case anyone is curious)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PICTURE
(
   ID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
engine=innodb;
```

**PICTURE_HISTORY table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PICTURE_HISTORY LIKE HISTORY;

ALTER TABLE PICTURE_HISTORY
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FOREIGNID) REFERENCES PICTURE(ID);
```

However, when I do this, I get:

```
Key column 'FOREIGNID' doesn't exist in table
```

I take this to mean that I have to first create `FOREIGNID`, but in many of the examples on SO, the above should work. Anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: I'd like to see an example where that should work... It won't work unless `FOREIGNID` already exists.  You cannot create a column simply by creating a constraint that uses it.

Comment: @Michael would I have to issue two alter statements (one to create `FOREGINID` and another to make it a FOREIGN KEY` or can I do it in one go?

Comment: Not actually sure - I've never tried it so I don't know if it will complain if you attempt one statement.  Just give it a try: `ALTER TABLE PICTURE_HISTORY ADD FOREIGNID INT NOT NULL ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pictureid FOREIGN KEY (FOREIGNID) REFERENCES PICTURE (ID);`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Thanks to [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael) for pointing out my mistake. I can't actually make a foreign key unless the column already exists. If instead I issue these two commands, the foreign key constraint is created:

```
ALTER TABLE PICTURE_HISTORY
ADD COLUMN FOREIGNID INT NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE PICTURE_HISTORY
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FOREIGNID) REFERENCES PICTURE(ID);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can combine commands for mysql using a comma, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE PICTURE_HISTORY
ADD COLUMN FOREIGNID INT NOT NULL,
ADD FOREIGN KEY (FOREIGNID) REFERENCES PICTURE(ID);
```

Comment: although not technically an answer to my original question, thanks for the tip nonetheless

Comment: alter table rooms add column productid  int not null, add foreign key(productid) references stock(productid) on delete cascade);   this didn't work.